# How to compare parts of different lengths in the same string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I need to create a function `my_fun` that given a string `msg` made only of the two characters `'o'` and `'x'`, returns the largest `n` for which there exist `n` equispaced `'x'` at distance `n` from each other in the string `msg`.

```
print ( my_fun('xox') )
```

output: 2, since there are two `x` at distance x(2)

```
print ( my_fun('ooxoxxxoooxxxoxo') )
```

output: 4, since there are four `x` at distance x(4)

I'm facing some troubles figuring out how to nest two for loops to analyze the string, storing the numbers representing the distance and then returning the max distance (which is the largest distance).

Note: I can't import any module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the smartest way, but it won't have nested for-loop.

try to get the highest n,
and get the positions, if there exists positions that are next to each other, then subtract the repeated x from the total.

```
def my_func(msg):

length_dict = {}
pos_dict = {}

split_x = msg.split('x')


for ind, val in enumerate(split_x):


    if val != '' and ind != len(split_x) -1 and ind != 0:
        length_dict[val] = length_dict.get(val, 0) + 1

        if val not in pos_dict.keys():
            pos_dict[val] = [ind]
        else:
            pos_dict[val].append(ind)


# sort dictionary
sorted_dict = sorted(length_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

maxO = 0

for key, val in length_dict.items():
    if val > maxO:
        maxO = val

# should have same length
topPos = [ pos_dict[i[0]] for i in sorted_dict if i[1] == maxO]
unpack = sorted([j for i in topPos for j in i])


prev = unpack[0]
countgap = 0
for i, v in enumerate(unpack):
    if i != 0:
        if v - prev == 1:
            countgap += 1

    prev = v


count_x = 2*len(unpack) - countgap


return count_x
```

some of the outcome:

```
msg1 = 'xox' # 2 x
msg2 = 'ooxoxxxoooxxxoooxoxo' # 7 x
msg3 = 'xooxoooxxoooxoox' # 6 x
msg4 = 'xooxxoox' # 4 x
msg5 = 'xooxoox' # 3 x
msg6 = 'oxoxxo' # 2 x
msg7 = 'oxxoxoxox' # 4 x
msg8 = 'oxoxoxox' # 4 x
msg9 = 'ooxoxxxoooxxxoxo' # 4x
```